# What is the underlying meaning of LxWxH=Volume?

Tags: volume, infinity

Say a rectangular solid has length=1, width=3, and height=5. Its base area would be 1x3=3. Its volume would be 5x3.

Now, 5x3 means 3+3+3+3+3, and each 3 represents the area of a 2D plane. So does this mean that the solid is only made up of 5 2D planes, instead of an infinite amount?

Comment: Are you confused about the same question one dimension lower? Do you believe that planes are only made up of a finite set of lines?